# MySQL Error on Persisting to Database Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

Problem:

I get the following MySQL error upon persisting an entity to database with doctrine, none of my Entity names are reserved words. I've tried numerous things including rebuilding the database and tables and running doctrine:schema:update but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Error:

> string(601) "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO
>   release (serial, title, artist, length, genre, description, tracks,
>   download, thumbnail, artwork) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
>   with params ["FREELOV", "afds", "asdf", "2:23", "asdf", "asdf",
>   "fdsaf=>2:23", "FREELOV.zip", "FREELOV.jpg", "FREELOVThumb.jpg"]:
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release
>   (serial, title, artist, length, genre, description, tracks, download,
>   th' at line 1"

Entity:

```
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Release
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="release")
 */

class Release
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $serial;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $title;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $artist;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $length;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)  
 */
protected $genre; # Array
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $description;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255) 
 */
protected $tracks; 
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $download;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255) 
 */
protected $thumbnail;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255) 
 */
protected $artwork;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

// Doctrine generated getters & setters
```

ReleaseController:

```
//namespaces and use statments

class ReleaseController extends Controller{

    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $release = new Release();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($release)
                    ->add('Artist', 'text')
                    ->add('Title', 'text')
                    ->add('Genre', 'text')
                    ->add('Description', 'textarea')
                    ->add('Tracks', 'text', array('attr' => array('style' => 'display:none')))
                    ->add('Length', 'text', array('label' => ' ', 'attr' => array('style' => 'display:none')))
                    ->add('addTrack', 'button', array('label'=>'+'))
                    ->add('Download', 'file') 
                    ->add('Thumbnail', 'file') 
                    ->add('Artwork', 'file') 
                    ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Add Release'))
                    ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid()){
            $rel = $this->createAction($form);

            dump($rel);

            $this->addToDB($rel);
        }

        return $this->render('cms/addRel.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

    }



    public function createAction(Form $form)
    {
        $release = new Release();
        $release->setSerial('FREELOV'.$release->getId());


        $artist = $form->get('Artist')->getData();
        $title = $form->get('Title')->getData();
        $genre = $form->get('Genre')->getData();
        $description = $form->get('Description')->getData();
        $tracks = $form->get('Tracks')->getData();
        $length = $form->get('Length')->getData();
        $download = $this->uploadAction($form, 'Download', $release);
        $thumb = $this->uploadAction($form, 'Artwork', $release);
        $art = $this->uploadAction($form, 'Thumbnail', $release);


        $release->setArtist($artist);
        $release->setTitle($title);
        $release->setLength($length);
        $release->setGenre($genre);
        $release->setDescription($description);
        $release->setTracks($tracks);
        $release->setDownload($download);
        $release->setThumbnail($thumb);
        $release->setArtwork($art);

        return $release;
    }

    public function uploadAction($form, $file, Release $rel)
    {
        $fileString = $rel->getSerial();

        #TODO: Needs to include error checking, use preg_match and $form[]->getData to make sure files are the right type
        switch($file)
        {
            case 'Download':
                $fileString = $fileString.'.zip';
            break;
            case 'Thumbnail':
                $fileString = $fileString.'Thumb.jpg';
                break;
            case 'Artwork':
                $fileString = $fileString.'.jpg';
            break;
        }

        $dir = 'bin/'; #FIXME: Needs to be directory for file uploads (maybe definable in the parameters.yml?)

        $form[''.$file]->getData()->move($dir, $fileString);
        return $fileString;
    }

    public function addToDB(Release $release)
    {
        try{
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($release);
        $em->flush();
        return new Response('New release added: '.$release->getArtist().' - '.$release->getTitle());
            }catch(\Exception $e){
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }

    }




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RELEASE` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL.

If you really want to have your table be named `release`, you must set the table name in the entity and qoute it, like this:

```
<?php

/**
  * @ORM\Enity
  * @ORM\Table(name="`release`")
  */
class Release;

…
```

However, if you still have the option to pick a different name, I would recommend doing so. This could save you from a lot of hassle later.